# PHP Float to int conversion returns incorrect values

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

I have a problem with probably was mentioned a lot of times, but unfortunately none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have the following code:

```
$starting_value = 0,57; // always float
$int_value = round($starting_value, 2); // rounding to 2 digits after comma since its currency calculations
$int_value = (int)($int_value * 100);
print "refund = ". $int_value; 
exit;
```

The problem is, that for $starting_value = 0.57 and 0.58, it returns respectively 56 and 57. For other values, like 1.33 or 0.22, it works correctly and returns 133 and 22. I assume that this is some kind of problem with how PHP treats float values, but how can I ensure that result will be correct?

I have tried:

- using round() on float
- casting float to double after rounding

But none of them worked. Any idea what else I can try?

$starting_value is typed into form and sent through $_REQUEST before doing those operations, if that matters.

Comment: Round after multiplying by 100, not before.

Comment: And don't use floating point for money.

Comment: So what type of variables should I use when precision matters? Double?

Comment: @MikaelDiak, if you don't know how to deal with float precision, then your best option is to use cents everywhere (integer). If you think that your education is good enough, then you can introduce an epsilon to all float math operations + you can use DECIMAL column type for DBMS.

Comment: @user1597430 yeah, I'd like to use cents, however what I'm creating is an app for "common users", and buyer specifically requested that value should be typed in dollars, rather than cents. Anyways, thanks for help!